# [UILabel length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance after using AutoLayout

Tags: xcode6, autolayout

I have a table view with custom cells which contains several views piled one on top of the other and one of them is instantiated using a XIB file. In that XIB file, I have a UIImage and two UILabels I've encapsulated in a UIView. I've figured out already this is the source of my exception but I don't understand why.
If I set hard-coded (instead of relative) constraints on the labels, i.e. fixed width and height it works.

I'm attaching a print screen that shows the constraints. Notice that in most constraints the constant = 0 otherwise it's stated in parentheses on the document outline. Also, the label's heights are 0.5 of their container's height.

Any clue to why it crashes?

Answer (score 16):

Just encountered and fixed this problem for me. We had a UILabel in a UIView, and that UILabel's outlet was called `title`.  When we asked our cell to 'layoutIfNeeded', we got the `UILabel length` exception. The -`viewForBaselineLayout` method on UIView mentions the word title.

We changed the outlet so it was called "cellTitle" **(anything but "title")** and this crash goes away.

Can you try changing your outlet name?

Comment: Thanks! You spared me hours of debugging :)

Comment: great catch and you saved my hours and brain cells! thanks very very much!

Comment: It happens only in iOS8 version.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using a static table . If you then remove methods as heightForFooterRow

make sure you autolayout, reset all and build app.